# How can I remove "RE:" when an email is replied on Salesforce

Tags: email

When I send an email on Salesforce, it adds RE: every each email. For example, in my 5th answered email subject seems like "RE:RE:RE:RE". How can I prevent that situation? Also, Can I remove "Sandbox: Re:" ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your email deliverability: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_send_from_salesforce_improve_deliverability.htm&type=5

if your email adresses linked with Microsoft Exchange, need support from system personnel, because me too i was live this problems, but it's not our problem, its about reel mail settings in Microsoft Exhange.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is related with salesforce automatic process which adds something to the emails' subject.

Comment: Can you try this -> Setup->Email Administration->Deliverability and make unchecked Enable Sender ID compliance.

Comment: This is not related with my problem. That setting is related with email authentication protocol. Please read guidelines for it.